# Removing first part of string?

Tags: php

Trying to edit urls in array.

```
[0] => https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/b115110/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011244
[1] => https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/p-ebisuminami88/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011205
```

As you see urls are like this. trying to remove first url and contain the second.

expected result is like:

```
https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011244
https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011205
```

what I tried is right below. In that way I can only remove the second. But how can I fix this code to remove first url in the string not the second.

```
$result = [];
foreach($setLinks as $key) {
   array_push($result, current(explode("/h", $key)));
}
```

Comment: `/h` is a bad string for splitting. `https://www.example.com/home/https://something` (check the `/home`). Another example is `https://www.example.com/ftp://something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate the task in 3 subtasks.

- First one being to capture the protocol using regex in example (the protocol of that url could be https, http, ftp ...)
- Then, capture the url itself, splitting the string using `://` as delimiter
- Finally, rebuild `protocol . "://" . url`

In example :

```
<?php
$array =
[
    'https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/b115110/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011244',
    'https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/p-ebisuminami88/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011205',
    'http://www.example.com/home/http://something',
    'http://www.example.com/https/ftp://something',
    'https://nothing.to.capture'
];

$result = array();
/*
 * matches a slash -> \/
 * followed by letters -> ([a-z]*)
 * followed by :// -> :\/\/
 * and capture the letters -> (the parenthesis)
 * it can match, in example : something/mycustomprotocol://somethingelse
 */
$pattern = "/\/([a-z]*):\/\//i";
foreach($array as $item) {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $item, $matches);
    if (count($matches) > 0)
    {
        $urls = explode("://", $item, 3);
        if (count($urls) > 2)
        {

            $protocol = $matches[1][0];
            $result[] = $protocol . "://" . $urls[2];

        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(83) "https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011244"
  [1]=>
  string(83) "https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011205"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "http://something"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "ftp://something"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` followed by `explode` to get split the string w.r.t `/https`. Below is the code:

```
$array = ['https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/b115110/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011244','https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/p-ebisuminami88/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011205'];
$result = [];
foreach($array as $arr){
  $getUrl = explode('/https', $arr);
  array_push($result, 'https' . $getUrl[1]);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: What if the protocol is `http` or `ftp` ? What if an url contains this : `https://www.example.com/courses/protocol/https/something/https://example2.com`

Comment: In that case, the solution would change and would be something around keyword `module`. I went ahead with `https` because the OP's question had the same in its example. `http` and `https` can be catered with above code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
$urls = [
    'https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/b115110/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011244',
    'https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/p-ebisuminami88/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011205'
];

foreach($urls as &$url){
    $url = 'http'.preg_split('/^.+?\/http/', $url, 2, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)[0];
}

print_r($urls);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011244
    [1] => https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011205
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d3835ff1fdd225459b4861068288b6c83e47ffa)

I set it up so that it would handle both `HTTP` and `HTTPS`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
unset($setLinks[0]);
foreach($setLinks as $key) {
   echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_replace` to remove the leading text:

```
foreach ($setLinks as &$value) {
    $value = preg_replace('#^.+(https?://.*)$#', '$1', $value);
}
print_r($setLinks);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011244
    [1] => https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011205 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/S2fJH)

Answer (score 0):

i miss understand  your question .kindly try it

```
<?php $quest = array("https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/b115110/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011244",
"https://www.proud-web.jp/mansion/p-ebisuminami88/https://www.proud-web.jp/module/structure/outline/BukkenOutline.xphp?code_no=011205");

foreach($quest as $q )
{
  $allquest = explode("/https",$q);
  echo "https".$allquest[1];

}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you posting a new answer instead of [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54743674/edit) your answer?